# Photon propagators in self-dual electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, maxwell-equations, propagator, duality

$\quad$Consider extending Maxwell electromagnetism with the dual photon field $\tilde{A}$.
The complex combinations $A^\pm = \frac{1}{2}(A \pm i\tilde{A})$ then serve as the potentials of the self-dual (SD) and anti-self-dual (ASD) field strengths, respectively:
\begin{align}
dA = F
\,,\quad
d\tilde{A} = -{*F}
\,,\quad
A^\pm = {\textstyle\frac{1}{2}}(A \pm i\tilde{A})
\quad\implies\quad
F^\pm = {\textstyle\frac{1}{2}}(1\mp i*)F = 
dA^\pm
\,.
\end{align}
The Maxwell Lagrangian $-\frac{1}{4} F^{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu}$ splits into SD and ASD contributions as $-\frac{1}{4} F^{+\mu\nu} F^+_{\mu\nu}$ plus $-\frac{1}{4} F^{-\mu\nu} F^-_{\mu\nu}$.
This implies that the $A^\pm$ fields have the same propagator as that of ordinary Maxwell electromagnetism.
For instance in the Lorenz gauge they are simply $\eta_{\mu\nu}/\square$.
Further, adding the interaction Lagrangian $J^+{}^\nu A^+_\nu + J^-{}^\nu A^-_\nu$, where $J^\pm{}^\nu$ denotes the SD/ASD currents, the field equation is derived as
\begin{align}
-\partial^\mu F^\pm_{\mu\nu}(x) = J^\pm_\nu(x)
\,.
\end{align}
The solution to this equation is simply obtained by "contracting" the currents with the propagator:
\begin{align}
A^\pm_\mu(x) = \frac{\eta_{\mu\nu}}{\square} J^\pm_\nu(x)
\,\,\,\text{(Lorenz gauge)}
\,,\quad
\square := -\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu
\,.
\end{align}
Say, a charged point particle is coupled with these $A^\pm$ fields.
Then the interaction action will read
\begin{align}
S_\text{int} = q\int d\sigma\; A_\mu(x(\sigma))\,\dot{x}^\mu(\sigma)
= q\int d\sigma\; \Big[ 
A^+_\mu(x(\sigma))\,\dot{x}^\mu(\sigma)
+ A^-_\mu(x(\sigma))\,\dot{x}^\mu(\sigma)
\Big]
\,,
\end{align}
since $A = A^+ + A^-$.
(A simple calculation shows that this indeed gives the Lorentz force law with correct normalization.)
If the particle is at rest, applying $A^\pm_\mu(x) = \eta_{\mu\nu}\square^{-1} J^\pm_\nu(x)$ gives
\begin{align}
A^\pm_\mu(x) = \left(-\frac{q}{4\pi|\vec{x}|},0,0,0\right) 
\implies
A_\mu(x) = \left(-\frac{2q}{4\pi|\vec{x}|},0,0,0\right) 
\,,\quad
\tilde{A}_\mu(x) = 0
\,.
\end{align}

$\quad$Now, I have two questions.

1. Why is the propagator just $\eta_{\mu\nu}/\square$?
   The Coulomb potential above can be thought of as deriving from a 4pt Feynman diagram.
   Switching the role of the "source" and the "probe" will revert the momentum direction of the internal propagator and, in turn, flip the helicity.
   So I'm wondering why is it not $A^\pm_\mu(x) = \eta_{\mu\nu}\square^{-1} J^\mp_\nu(x)$ but $A^\pm_\mu(x) = \eta_{\mu\nu}\square^{-1} J^\pm_\nu(x)$.
   (The SD current $J^+$ has a 3pt vertex with an incoming plus-helicity photon from the $A^+ J^+$ term.
   Then for the probe particle the photon appears as an incoming minus-helicity photon so that it interacts with the $A^- J^-$ vertex.
   In this light, the 4pt diagram should mediate between SD and ASD currents.
   But $A^\pm_\mu(x) = \eta_{\mu\nu}\square^{-1} J^\pm_\nu(x)$ says that SD currents interacts with SD currents.
   Am I making confusion with real Maxwell electromagnetism?)
2. The electric potential $A^0(x)$ turns out to be ${2q}/{4\pi|\vec{x}|}$.
   What makes the factor-of-$2$ mismatch?
   It seems that the $S_\text{int}$ above does give the Lorentz force law with correct normalization, which means that it works fine for the "probe" particle.
   But why not for the "source" particle?
   I have tried changing normalizations here and there (such as $A^\pm = \frac{a}{2}(A \pm i\tilde{A})$, $J = b(J^+ + J^-)$, etc.), but the final Coulomb result turns out to be independent with such rescalings.

.........

Just for reference: my metric is $\eta_{\mu\nu} = \mathrm{diag}(-1,+1,+1,+1)$, and the metric volume form convention is $\varepsilon_{0123} = +1$ with $(*F)^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} F_{\rho\sigma}$.
Self-dual is $\ast=+i$, anti-self-dual is $\ast = -i$.

Comment: Okay, I've found a satisfactory answer. The key is that the "naive self-dualization" of the Maxwell theory presented in the question fails, and more careful analysis with the Zwanziger two-potential formulation is needed. Then the propagators conserve helicity and the factor-of-2 issue also gets resolved! I'll consider leaving these as a self-answer later after everything becomes clear.